# Union with Comparer

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

I have a list of items and I am trying to get the distinct recored,

Some record has no Id (0) and some has Id, is it possible to get the ones with Id?

```
void Main() {

var a = new Skill {Id =0, Name="test"};
var b = new Skill {Id =0, Name="test"};
var c = new Skill {Id= 1, Name="test" }; // masterlist skill
var listA = new List<Skill> { a, b };
var listB = new List<Skill> { c };

var result = listA.Union(listB, new SkillComparer());

result.Dump();
} 

public class SkillComparer : IEqualityComparer<Skill>
{

#region IEqualityComparer<Skill> Members

public bool Equals(Skill skill, Skill skillToCompare)
{
    return skill.Name == skillToCompare.Name;
}

public int GetHashCode(Skill obj)
{
    return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
}

#endregion
}

 public class Skill {
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
```

Result

```
ID:0 | Name: Test
```

Is there a way it returns the materlist's id?

```
ID:1 | Name: Test
```

Comment: You need to change your `SkillComparer`

Comment: @MillieSmith I tried  return `skill.Name == skillToCompare.Name && skill.Id > skillToCompare.Id;` but to no luck

Comment: It's an equals. Do you want it to compare and indicate which one is greater and return the greatest?

Comment: The greatest id out of all of them? or the greatest id for a specific name? Can there be more than one "greatest"?

Comment: I assumed that the expected result was a list of Skills, each with a unique Name and each containing the maximum Id for its name

Comment: What is wrong with     `listA.Concat(listB).Where(r=>r.Id != 0)` ?

Comment: @sgmoore The problem with `listA.Concat(listB).Where(r=>r.Id != 0)` is that if there were more than one skill in a "name" group with an id greater than zero, there would be a duplicate in the list. `listA.Concat(listB).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).Distinct(new SkillComparer())` would handle this situation.

Comment: @sgmoore Perhaps it would be more efficient to combine ours into the following: `listA.Concat(listB).Where(r=>r.Id != 0).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).Distinct(new SkillComparer())`

Comment: @sgmoore Or if the id's in a name group that were greater than zero were always the same, it could be shortened to this: `listA.Concat(listB).Where(r=>r.Id != 0).Distinct(new SkillComparer())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq:

```
var result = listA.Concat(listB).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).Distinct(new SkillComparer());
```

This yields a distinct list of Skills by Name, each containing the maximum Id of its Name.

```
var a = new Skill {Id =0, Name="test"};
var b = new Skill {Id =2, Name="test"};
var c = new Skill {Id= 1, Name="test" };
var d = new Skill { Id = 3, Name = "foo" };
var e = new Skill { Id = 0, Name = "foo" };

var listA = new List<Skill> { a, b };
var listB = new List<Skill> { c, d, e };

var result = listA.Concat(listB).OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).Distinct(new SkillComparer());

foreach (var skill in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", skill.Name, skill.Id));
}
```

Results:

```
foo: 3
test: 2
```

Comment: I would still want the distinct

Comment: Ordering first should allow the highest Id to be kept in the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are more efficient ways, but from what I know about the question:

```
listA.AddRange(listB).Where(o => o.Name == desiredName).Max(o => o.Id);
```